# Were so-called "mlecchas" sacrificed to the Gods?

Tags: sacrifice, mleccha

https://archive.org/stream/ShivaPurana/Bhavishya%20Purana_djvu.txt

> Suta Goswami said: Once upon a time in Plastinapura, Pradyota the son of Kshemaka was leading an assembly and meanwhile the great sage Narada arrived there. King Pradyota happily honored him. Plaving him seated on the seat the sage told king Pradyota, "Your father was killed by the mlecchas, therefore he attained Yamaloka or the hellish planet. If you perform a = mleccha-yajna‘, then by the effect of this sacrifice your father will attain the heavenly planets."
>
> Flearing this king Pradyota immediately called the best of the learned Brahmanasand
> started = mleccha-yajna‘ in Kuruksetra. They built a yajna-kunda which was 16 yojanas in
> square (128 miles). They meditated on the demigods and offered oblations of mlecchas.
> There are haras, hunas, barvaras, gurundas, sakas, khasas, yavanas, pallavas,romajas
> and those who are situated in different dvipas and in kamaru, china and the middle ofthe
> ocean; all of them were called with the mantra and burnt to ashes. Then he (the king)
> gave dakshina (donation) to the brahmanas and performed abhiseka. As a result his
> father Kshemaka went to the heavenly planets. After that he became famous everywhere
> as a mleccha-hanta or destroyer of mlecchas.

Is this considered authentic?

Does any other scripture talk about sacrificing "Mlecchas"?

Whatever maybe said of "Mlecchas" - scripture has never denied that they are human.  So, if genuine, this is a clear statement that human sacrifice was part of Hinduism.

Comment: I think the composer of this story, might have followed the story of Sarpa yagna of Mahabharata

Comment: Yes, there are yajnas in the Vedas to genocide people. Parashara did this to the Rakshasas. Janamejaya did this to the Nagas. And as your citation shows, Pradyota did this to the mlecchas.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this considered authentic?

This is most likely not authentic, because in the Mahabharata, Krishna himself says that humans are not to be sacrificed to the gods. He strongly censures Jarasamdha for sacrificing humans.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02022.htm

> Krishna said,--'O thou of mighty arms, there is a certain person of the head of a (royal) line who upholdeth the dignity of his race At his command have we come against thee. Thou hast brought, O king, many of the Kshatriyas of the world as captives (to thy city.) Having perpetrated that wicked wrong how dost thou regard thyself as innocent? O best of monarchs, how can a king act wrongfully towards other virtuous kings? But thou, O king, treating other kings with cruelty, seekest to offer them as sacrifice unto the god Rudra! O son of Vrihadratha, this sin committed by thee may touch even us, for as we are virtuous in our practices, we are capable of protecting virtue. **The slaughter of human being as sacrifice unto the gods is never seen.** Why dost thou, therefore, seek to perform a sacrifice unto god Sankara by slaughtering human beings? Thou art addressing persons belonging to thy own order as animals (fit for sacrifice)! Fool as thou art, who else, O Jarasandha, is capable of behaving in this way?...